# Can not sort csv data using date & day using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, csv, mysqli, fopen

There is this dynamic csv file that keeps changing and I am writing a php software to sort the reservations with respect to date and day i.e selecting day or date and showing only those reservations.

```
<?php
echo "<html><body><table>\n\n";
$f = fopen("reservation.csv", "r");
for ($x = 0; ($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false ; $x++) {
        echo "<tr>";

foreach ($line as $cell) {
                    echo "<td>" . htmlspecialchars($cell) . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>\n";
}

fclose($f);
echo "\n</table></body></html>";
```

also available at http://drunkendragonbicknacre.co.uk/custom/test.php
Could you please help me figure this out, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't tag questions with unrelated tags.

Comment: As for the question: read the CSV file into a two-dimensional array, then use array functions on it to filter and sort it.